# Start chrome with zoom at 100%

Tags: google-chrome, cmd, parameters

I want to start chrome with 100% Zoom using the cmd. Sometimes it opens up with another zoom setup due to previus use. I got this line on cmd to open it but want to set the zoom also

```
start chrome --start-maximized ""https://www.google.es""
```

Any suggestions?

Tried with this one, not working

```
start chrome --start-maximized /force-device-scale-factor=1 "https://www.google.es"
```

Comment: Does Chrome have an option for doing that? or are you asking us exactly that? This site does not provide assistance with software settings, switches and parameters, so you'll need to find out what those are, implement it, and experience an issue in using that, before we can assist you here.

Comment: @Compo looked for that parameter but didnt find anything. Just asking if someone knows how to do it with CMD

Comment: Your question is off topic then! This site helps people with a fix or workaround for a specifc, and properly explained, issue, for their provided code. The code you've supplied works, and does not attempt to perform the task you've laid out in your question. Until you've added code which attempts the task you require of it, your question is simply about Google Chrome, its settings, switches and parameters.

Comment: @Compo updated with a try , but without success

Comment: Not working is not reasonable description of what happened. Please properly explain what happened when you used that? and what debugging methods you've used? You're not a new member of this site, and should know better about the requirements for a good, clear and answerable question. BTW, I'd recommend that you use `Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-maximized /force-device-scale-factor=1 "https://www.google.es"`. What happens when you run it also with `/high-dpi-support=1`? Which version of Chrome are you having this issue with?